# combine multiple domain in google analytics

Tags: dns, google-analytics

Can someone please let me know if i have 2 separate domain in my google analytics

for e.g:

```
abc.com
xyz.abc.com
```

The second domain is 3rd party shopping cart.

Right now there is reporting for both separate, but I want to have them together so I can eventually set up goal and conversion tracking.

Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: i think this would be more suiteable on the [webmaster stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, your 3rd party shopping cart will be tracked if you set up google analytics for abc.com.  This is because xyz.abc.com is a subdomain of abc.com.

You should read through this page of the GA docs for understanding: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite